# Unable to call inet function from L3Address

Tags: omnet++, inet

Im trying to port this old code IPvXAddress to L3 Address from inet. But received this error:

'no matching function for call to ‘inet::L3Address::get()"

This is my code:

```
L3Address addr = L3AddressResolver().resolve(token);
if (excludeLocalDestAddresses && rt && rt->isLocalAddress(addr.get()))
continue;
```

This is inet::L3Address's get() Function:

```
uint64 L3Address::get(AddressType type) const
{
    if (getType() == type)
        return lo;
    else
        throw cRuntimeError("Address is not of the given type");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not providing the `AddressType` parameter to the `get()` function. It should be something like: `get(AddressType::IPv4)`